# Nested genitive?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I just said this to a friend:

> Ecce in hac pagina [vox](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5613/118) **Iohannis Ørbergii** capitula a primo usque ad decimum *Linguae Latinae Per Se Illustratae* **legentis**:
>
> https://sites.google.com/site/sobrinointroductiontolatin/audio-recordings

I've got the genitive *Linguae Latinae* modifying *capitula* in between the genitive **Iohannis Ørbergii** and its modifier **legentis**. Can you…*do* that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're asking if you can nest genitives, of course you can. This particular one is a bit extreme, and sounds more poetical to me, but the practice is fine. Compare Cicero's *Republic* 1.13.10:

> unius aetatis **clarissimorum ac sapientissimorum nostrae civitatis virorum** disputatio repetenda memoria est.

Here, *clarissimorum ac sapientissimorum* modify *virorum*, with *nostrae civitatis* in the middle: "the most distinguished and wisest men of our commonwealth."

In Greek, I've seen the nesting encompass quite a lot, too, and in poetry it's not uncommon to see some examples on the extreme side.

Comment: That's a lot of genitives! I was thinking that it's still disambiguated by number and gender (the *-orum* adjectives can't modify *civitatis*), but wait—isn't there a third layer of nesting here? That is, does _unius aetatis_ modify _virorum_ (as genitive of genitive, not adjective modifying genitive)?