# A range of chapters

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

How do you grammatically denote a range of chapters, like what I'm trying to do in this sentence?

> Ecce in hac pagina [vox](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5613/118) Iohannis Ørbergii **capitula prima usque decima** *Linguae Latinae Per Se Illustratae* legentis:
>
> https://sites.google.com/site/sobrinointroductiontolatin/audio-recordings

Should it be **capitula primum usque decimum** instead? Or **capitulum**?

And does **usque** suit denoting a full range rather the just the destination?

(If you're wondering about the nested genitives, see [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5614/118).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparently simple question produced before this a single answer and much interesting comment.

I would put it simply as [Ecce in hac pagina Iohannis Ørbergii] *primum usque ad decimum capitulorum*. The genitive plural suggests there there are further chapters.

Answer (score 4):

I would offer two options:

> *…capitula a primo (usque) ad decimum…*
>   …chapters from the first one (all the way) to the tenth…

Or:

> *…a primo capitulo (usque) ad decimum…*
>   …from the first chapter one (all the way) to the tenth…

I would not repeat the word *capitulum* twice unless I wanted more emphasis.
Perhaps the second one is more idiomatic, but the first one is clear, too.
(It has an implicit *capitulum* which is easy enough for the reader to supply in the correct form.)
The first one has the benefit that the word *capitula* has a clear case and the grammatical role is more transparent; it's a matter of choosing between a noun phrase and an adverbial phrase.

When using *usque* to express the length of a range, [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=usque&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) indicate that you should use a preposition.
To be honest, I had hard time parsing the bold part of your sentence.
If nothing else, prepositions make the the range clearer.

Notice that you can leave *usque* out if you will, just as you can drop "all the way" in English.
It is a matter of tone and emphasis.

Making *prima* and *decima* plural sounds fishy; there are several chapters but only one first and one tenth.
You could say *capitula primum et decimum* for "the first and tenth chapters", which does not explicitly indicate a range.
It is also correct to say *capitulum primum et decimum*.
See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5620/79) for further details.

The agreement of a noun with several adjectives makes it reasonable, to me at least, to use *capitula a primo ad decimum* without repeating *capitulum* in the relevant case after the prepositions.
It is clear what the numerals refer to, so I would consider it clumsy and unnecessary to repeat the noun.

There is a somewhat similar range expression in *Ab Urbe condita* 31.1:

> *…tres et sexaginta annos—tot enim sunt **a primo Punico ad secundum bellum** finitum…*

I will look for more range examples, but I hope this makes my *a primo ad decimum* more plausible.

Comment: I'm still thinking this through. Indeed _usque_ is an adverb, and I was using it as a preposition. So, I'm giving up on _usque;_ I simply want to denote a range. Questions: (1) Does your first version have implied nouns like this: *…capitula a primo capitulo ad decimum capitulum*? (2) In the last version (not denoting a range), don't the ordinal-number adjectives need to agree with the noun they modify, _capitula,_ rather than the number of chapters that each denotes (i.e. one)?

Comment: @BenKovitz *Usque* cannot be used as a preposition as far as I know, but can be used with one. (1) There are implied nouns the same way in the Latin (*a primo capitulo ad decimum capitulum*) and English ("from the first chapter to the tenth chapter") versions. I would argue there is no implied noun, some might disagree, but the two languages are similar here. (2) If there are many things but only one of each kind, it is possible (necessary, I think) to have the noun in plural but each adjective in singular. Ordinals are essentially adjectives. This point is worth a separate question, though.

Comment: (1) In English, one can say "the first through tenth chapters". I suppose it's debatable, but I understand _first_ and _tenth_ to directly modify _chapters_ with no additional implied nouns. I was thinking that Latin could do this, too, but your answer has (so far) swayed me to think that it can't, because the prepositions put the adjectives into a different case than the noun being modified. Am I mistaken? (2) [Alia quaestio](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5620/118) facta est.

Comment: @BenKovitz (1) I find it somewhat irrelevant that the case is different. In any case, the noun is semantically implied in any language, and I'm not even sure what it would meant for it to be grammatically implied. I find the question of implied nouns to be one of points of view, not one of grammatical rules. (2) Good! There is a chance that it turns out to be a duplicate, but it's an important question nevertheless.

Comment: Regarding (1), the grammatical difference that I have in mind is what noun is modified by each adjective. In English, lacking noun-adjective agreement, the adjectives _first_ and _tenth_ can directly modify _chapters_ even though one of the adjectives is the object of a preposition. But in Lat㏌, it appears that _primo_ and _decimum_ can't modify _capitula._ No? Or are there circumstances in Latin where an adjective and the noun that it modifies can disagree in case, number, or person? (Perhaps one could avoid the theoretical implied nouns by saying that the adjectives are being used as nouns.)

Comment: @BenKovitz I have to disagree. *Primo* and *decimum* can modify an implicit *capitulum* without problems. (The same happens in Finnish if that's relevant.) The noun *capitulum* can be implicitly understood in the required case. The gender of the numeral or adjective agrees with the relevant noun, but there is no need to repeat the noun when a new case is used. That would be horribly clumsy. I see no problem with this: *Duos canes habeo. Unus est filius alterius.* The words *unus* (nom.) and *alterius* (gen.) refer to *canes* (acc.). If you're not convinced, I can look for examples later.

Comment: @BenKovitz I updated the answer with a link to the other question about agreement and a citation of a similar range expression by Livius.

Comment: Thanks—I'm convinced. I just updated [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5614/118) with the correct declensions. (And thanks for letting me know about Finnish. Indeed I was curious.)

Comment: I would probably amend to "a primo capítulo usque ad decimum." But I can't elaborate now :)

Comment: @brianpck That might be an option. Would you not have the accusative *capitula* at all to act as an object, or would you just have only one *capitulum* in the sentence?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Echoing brianpck, Latin often elides one word if it's used again in the same way, though I typically have seen it leave off the first, not second, word. So my very minor variation would be "a primo usque ad decimum capitulum."

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I still feel that the plural accusative *capitula* is useful, as nothing else indicates the grammatical role of the chapters as clearly. I may of course be mistaken (and it wouldn't be the first time), but a range expression with a suitable accusative noun in that sentence sounds weird to me. I would be interested to know whether it would be idiomatic or grammatical to leave the *capitula* out. Or did you mean *capitula a primo ad decimum capitulum* with the same noun twice?