# Ordinal adjectives for single things modifying plural noun?

Tags: grammar-choice, adjective, numbers, agreement

To refer to "the first and second chapters", do I say:

> capitula prima et secunda

or:

> capitula primum et secundum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the noun can be singular or plural but the ordinals should be singular.
That is, you'd need *capitulum* or *capitula* with *primum et secundum*.
If you go with *capitula prima et secunda*, it sounds like there are several first chapters and several second chapters as in a collection of books.
(At least I found no evidence to support this possibility to express what you want.)

[§234.1 of Bennett's New Latin Grammar](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect234) says:

> Two Adjectives in the Singular may limit a noun in the Plural, as; **prīma et vīcēsima legiōnēs**, *the first and twentieth legions*.

The example in the Grammar seems to be lifted from Tacitus:

> *Primam ac vicesimam legiones Caecina legatus in civitatem Vbiorum reduxit…*
>   (*Annales*, 1.37)

However, it is also possible for the noun to be singular:

> *Primam et secundam aciem in armis esse…*
>   (Caesar, *De Bello Gallico*, 1.49)